# Get data from third page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form my conditions are,

1. form.php, where I am inserting data using form,
2. display.php where I am showing data in table form using pagination and
3. validation.js where I am validating form data as well as I have following function

   ```
    $('#pagiCount a').click(function(){
           $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(response) {
               console.log(response);
               $( "#result" ).html(response);
               });
           return false;
           //alert($(this).attr('href'));
       });
   ```

Now I want to show that form from form.php on same display.php after pagination table.
How I can do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Suggeston :

Whenever you display the data in the ajax.php , just create a session array variable and update that value in the session array variable. So when ever you display the value in the ajax.php , get the data from the session array variable and display it.

Code : ajax.php

```
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)){  
    $_SESSION['compare_array'][]=$result; 
    } 
     echo "<table>"; 

    foreach($_SESSION['compare_array'] as $key => $result)
    { 

        echo '<tr><td>'.$result['brand'].'</td>'.'<td width="150" height="10">'.$result['model'].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$result['clr'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$result['sim'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$result['os']‌​.'</td>'.'</td></tr>'; 

    } 

echo "</table>";
```

OLD Suggestion :

You can use $.ajax with datatype : json. so you can return the data array in json encoded format so you can return both pagination result data and the form html data in array.

```
echo json_encode("pagination_response" => "put pagination html here", "form_data_response"  => "put form html here ");


    $('#pagiCount a').click(function(){
                $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $( "#result" ).html(response);
                    });
                return false;
                //alert($(this).attr('href'));
            });


     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",  // post or get
            url: 'your_url',
            data: "data_href="+ $(this).attr('href'),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response)
            { 
        if(result.status =="success")
        { 

            $( "#result" ).html(response.pagination_response);
            $( "#result_form_html" ).html(response.form_data_response);



            }
        });
```

Comment: where should I put that json_encode() statement.? In which file?  If I am not wrong, it should be in one of php file....but in my case, where should I put it, in form.php or display.php ?

Comment: i have this table in display.php--->>

echo '<form name="data" id="data" action="ajax.php" method="post" onclick="show()">';
echo '<table style="width:600px; cell-padding:4px; cell-spacing:0; margin:auto;" border="1">';   /*other <td>with while loop */ echo '<td> <input type="checkbox" name="mobile[]" class="mobile" value="'.$result['id'].'" ></td>'.'</tr>';}
echo '</table>';
 echo '<center><input type=submit name="compare" value="compare" id="compare" class="compare" style="margin-top:10px"></center> ';
echo '</form>';

Comment: my table in ajax.php--->>

echo '<table class="result_table" id="result_table" style="width:600px; cell-padding:4px; cell-spacing:0; margin:auto;" border="1">';
echo'<th>Company</th><th>Model</th><th>Color</th><th>SIM</th><th>OS</th></tr>'; 
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo '<tr><td>'.$result['brand'].'</td>'.'<td width="150" height="10">'.$result['model'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$result['clr'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$result['sim'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$result['os'].'</td>'.'</td></tr>';
echo '</table>';

Comment: and this fucntion i have written in display.php--->>

<script>
function show() {
var url = "ajax.php";
$.ajax({type: "POST",
url: url,
data: $("#data").serialize(),
success: function(data){document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = data;
}});
return false;}
</script>

Comment: Still I am not getting desired result in <div id="here"></div>
when i click on table any where,it giving result of (display.php)
echo '<table class="result_table"  id = "result_table" style="width:600px; cell-padding:4px; cell-spacing:0; margin:auto;" border="1">';
echo'<th>Company</th><th>Model</th><th>Color</th><th>SIM</th><th>OS</th></tr>';

and when i check ckeckboxes,it is giving me comparison on display.php
and when i click on compare button,it is giving me same result on ajax.php
I want ,when i click on compare bitton, it should show comparion on same display.php  what are i mistakes?

Comment: now i got result on display.php but thing is, i have used pagination for table(in which i have check boxes), so when i select few mobiles to compare, it shows me comparison for those values and when i go on next page and select few mobiles, first it shows current comparison table n then previous page comparison table (i want to add diffrent pages comparison in same table)..how I can do that ?

Comment: Please help me in this matter, how I can do that?

Comment: i have updated my answer check the "New suggestion" part